# Aligning Equations with Different Cases

Tags: equations

How can I align these equations by keeping equal signs aligned?

```
\begin{align*}
     & (x^2-5x+4)^2-8(x^2-5x+4)-20 &= 0 &\\
     & u^2-8u-20 &= 0 \\
     & (u-10)(u+2) &= 0 \\
     u &= 10 \quad &\text{or} \quad u &=-2\\
     x^2-5x+4 &=10 & x^2-5x+4 &= -2\\
     x^2-5x-6 &= 0 & x^2-5x+6 &= 0\\
\end{align*}
```

It seems like aligning the top part of the equations as well.

Comment: Why do you want the = signs aligned? The result is, as you see in the answers below, pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those equals signs are only loosely related to one another. Don't align them.

[image]

Well, “bad” is not so bad after all, but the titles should be those, shouldn't they?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Ugly}

\begin{align*}
&\begin{aligned}
(x^2-5x+4)^2-8(x^2-5x+4)-20 &= 0 \\
u^2-8u-20 &= 0 \\
(u-10)(u+2) &= 0
\end{aligned}
\\
&\begin{aligned}[t]
u&=10 \\
x^2-5x+4 &= 10 \\
x^2-5x-6 &= 0
\end{aligned}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
u &=-2\\
x^2-5x+4 &= -2\\
x^2-5x+6 &= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\section{Bad}

\begin{align*}
&\begin{aligned}
&(x^2-5x+4)^2-8(x^2-5x+4)-20 = 0 \\
&u^2-8u-20 = 0 \\
&(u-10)(u+2) = 0
\end{aligned}
\\
&\begin{aligned}[t]
&u=10 \\
&x^2-5x+4 = 10 \\
&x^2-5x-6 = 0
\end{aligned}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
&u =-2\\
&x^2-5x+4 = -2\\
&x^2-5x+6 = 0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\section{Good}

\begin{gather*}
(x^2-5x+4)^2-8(x^2-5x+4)-20 = 0 \\
u^2-8u-20 = 0 \\
(u-10)(u+2) = 0
\\
\begin{gathered}[t]
u=10 \\
x^2-5x+4 = 10 \\
x^2-5x-6 = 0
\end{gathered}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{gathered}[t]
u =-2\\
x^2-5x+4 = -2\\
x^2-5x+6 = 0
\end{gathered}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
      (x^2-5x+4)^2-8(x^2-5x+4)-20 &= 0 \\
      u^2-8u-20 &= 0 \\
      (u-10)(u+2) &= 0 \\
     u &= 10 \quad \text{or} &u &=-2\\
     x^2-5x+4 &=10 & x^2-5x+4 &= -2\\
     x^2-5x-6 &= 0 & x^2-5x+6 &= 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]